# java.lang.numberformatexception

Tags: java, socket

El servidor recibe por parámetros un número, se lo envía al servidor después de ser pasado de cadena a bytes y este recibe esa cadena, la transforma en un entero para hacer una simple suma y devuelve el resultado al cliente, pero no me deja pasar esa cadena a un int por lo que entiendo.

```
            DatagramPacket peticion = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            //Recibo el datagrama
            socketUDP.receive(peticion);
            System.out.println("Recibo la informacion del cliente");

            //Convierto lo recibido y mostrar el mensaje
            String numCadena = new String(peticion.getData());
            int M = Integer.parseInt(numCadena);     //Creo que el error está en esta línea
            System.out.println("M es " + M);

            //Obtengo el puerto y la direccion de origen
            //Sino se quiere responder, no es necesario
            int puertoCliente = peticion.getPort();
            InetAddress direccion = peticion.getAddress();
            int N = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            int suma = N + M;
            System.out.println("La suma es "+suma);
            String resultado = Integer.toString(suma);
          // mensaje = "¡Hola mundo desde el servidor!";
            buffer = resultado.getBytes();
```

Comment: Hola Miguel, ¿ da algún error ? ayudaría ver la traza del mismo, además sería interesante ver el valor de `numCadena ` ANTES de hacer el `parseInt()`, para ver qué es lo que está recibiendo en realidad

Comment: Creo que ya he solucionado ese error, he añadido un .String numCadena = new String(peticion.getData()).trim(); Muchas gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Ok, genial, por cierto, para ayudar a otros usuarios podrías indicar cmo respuesta la línea que modificaste y así además aparecerá la pregunta como respondida.